# KafkaStream cannot stream data from topic using Avro

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am building an application to get gain hands-on experience with KafkaStreams, which I have been successful with so far. However, when I specifically try to build a Stream to a topic that is serialized using Avro, it fails.

The consumer group ID is registered in the cluster, however it is not subscribed to a topic. As seen below on the image.

First column displaying its number of consumer and second being the number of topics

[image]

The code below is my configuration of the Kafka Stream.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Defining the properties for the stream
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "Test-stream-UserRegistrationServicebbb");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
        //Defining the serde for the value
        Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
        SpecificAvroSerde<Pending_Registrations> pendingRegistrationsSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        pendingRegistrationsSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        //Creating a stream from the topic with specific serde
        KStream<String, Pending_Registrations> userStream = builder.stream("User.Pending-Registrations",
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), pendingRegistrationsSerde));
        //Printing the stream
        userStream.foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + value));
        //starting the stream
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        streams.start();
    }
```

The `Pending_Registration` class is generated from an Avro schema (specifically from a .avsc file).

All services except the java applications are deployed using docker on ports: zookeeper: 2181, kafka: 9092, schema-registry: 8081, confluent control center: 9021
The application compiles and runs without any errors or crashes, it just doesn't print out anything nor find any topic.

I'd really appreciate any help, since I've spent the last 5 hours trying to figure out what I have missed. :)

I have tried following multiple guides to find where any discrepancies between our code, but unfortuneatly their solution did not seem to work in my case.

An ordinary consumer is working perfectly fine with avro and is able to deserialize all of the stored messages:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties streamConfig = new Properties();
        streamConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "Test-normal-UserRegistrationService");
        streamConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        streamConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().deserializer().getClass());
        streamConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
        streamConfig.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
        streamConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        KafkaConsumer<String, Pending_Registrations> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(streamConfig);
        consumer.subscribe(java.util.Collections.singletonList("User.Pending-Registrations"));
        while (true) {
            consumer.poll(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(100)).forEach(record -> {
                System.out.println("key: " + record.key() + " value: " + record.value());
            });
        }
    }
```

No errors are thrown when I comment out the schema registry url configs, the SerdeConfig.

Comment: 1) Please show your docker compose. Port forwards aren't enough to connect to Kafka 2) Please add slf4j dependencies so that you actually get to see the errors that happen and increase log level to DEBUG

Comment: @OneCricketeer
Thanks a lot for the reply. I really appreciate that you want to help me :)
1) Here's a link for the docker-compose file: https://justpaste.it/2mdoa
2) I wasn't aware that I had to use slf4j in order to get logs from Kafka. Thanks! It seems that an error is being thrown. Here is a stacktrace of the logs. 
https://justpaste.it/cj0rt

Comment: Please [edit] rather than use external links. I see `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.Readable.readArray` - so please edit your question again to include your how you're managing dependencies. Seems like you!may have a version issue

Comment: @OneCricketeer
I was hesitant to edit and add hundred lines of code to the post, so I used a third party text store instead. I apologize if this against conventions of stack overflow. 
Thanks a lot for your help. I managed to solve this issue when I read your message.
I wrote an answer about what caused the issue, but forgot to press post...
SLF4J helped a lot, thanks for introducing me to that library, I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Didn't need to be hundreds of lines, but we do ask for a [mcve]. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @OneCricketeer
I'll adhere to that standard next time I'll post on stack overflow. :)

Figuring out the solution was very relieving, since that I'll use KafkaStreams and KTables for another 6 microservices in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @OneCricketeer for his help on helping me solve what I had overlooked.

It turns out that the version of Kafka Stream and Confluent Platform that I used was not compatible.
After using the versions:
confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
'kafka-streams', version: '3.4.1'

The issue was resolved and the Kafka Stream could start streaming.

Comment: Note: this version release was only a few days ago, so Kafka 3.3.2, for example, is considered "safer" for now